# Error cuando intento mandar el formulario por mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Pues eso, intento conectar la parte php y una de dos:

O me da el siguiente error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\nuevo1\registro.php on line 8

O este:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$email' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\nuevo1\registro.php on line 9"

Soy muy nuevo con PHP, dejo aquí la parte del form y los archivos php.

Form:

```
<?php
    include("registro.php");
?>

<div class="form" id="rect">

    <h3 class="xd">  Regístrese de forma segura.   </h3>
    <form action="registro.php" method="POST">


        <br>
        <label> Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Cree un usuario" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label> E-mail</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ponga su e-mail" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Móvil</label>
        <input type="text" name="movil" placeholder="Ponga su número de teléfono sin +34" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        
        <label>Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Cree una contraseña segura" required>
        <br>
        <br>
        <span class="msg-error error"></span>
<div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcWcDUcAAAAAIVhNArhuB2P1jJvFN_BlasqPb2i"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar Captcha" />
<br>
<br>

        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="registrarme">
    </form>
</div>
```

PHP:

Conexión de Db:

```
<?php
    $conex = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dude"); 
?>
```

Envío de datos:

```
<?php 
include("con_db.php");
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    if (strlen($_POST['usuario']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['email']) >= 1)
    (strlen($_POST['movil']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['pw']) >= 1) {
        $usuario = trim($_POST['usuario'])
        $email = trim($_POST['email'])
        $movil = trim($_POST['movil'])
        $pw = trim($_POST['pw'])
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO `login`(usuario, email, movil, pw) VALUES 
     ('[usuario]','[email]','[movil]','[pw]')"
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
        if ($resultado) {
            ?> 
            <h3 class="ok">¡Te has inscripto correctamente!</h3>
           <?php
        } else {
            ?> 
            <h3 class="bad">¡Ups ha ocurrido un error!</h3>
           <?php
        }
    }   else {
            ?> 
            <h3 class="bad">¡Por favor complete los campos!</h3>
           <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Se me olvidó decir que el error: :"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\nuevo1\registro.php on line 8" aparece cuando en la parte de envío del form, concretamente en:
 $usuario = trim($_POST['usuario'])
    $email = trim($_POST['email'])
    $movil = trim($_POST['movil'])
    $pw = trim($_POST['pw'])
Le añado ";"
Cuando se lo elimino me sale el otro error, es decir, "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$email' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\nuevo1\registro.php on line 9"

Answer (score 2):

En el segundo condicional :

```php
if (strlen($_POST['usuario']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['email']) >= 1) "AQUI"
(strlen($_POST['movil']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['pw']) >= 1)
```

Te Falta concatenar las condiciones, debes revisar esta condición.

Además te falta los `;` después de las asignaciones.

---

Tomas este código y podrías realizar otra condición, para NO amarrar TODO a una sola condición

```
if (!EMPTY($_POST['usuario']) && !EMPTY($_POST['email']) && !EMPTY($_POST['movil'])  && !EMPTY($_POST['pw'])) {
        $usuario = trim($_POST['usuario']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $movil = trim($_POST['movil']);
        $pw = trim($_POST['pw']);
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO `login`(usuario, email, movil, pw) VALUES 
     ('[usuario]','[email]','[movil]','[pw]')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
```

debes finalizar cada línea con `;`

Comment: Cómo podría concatenarlo?